# Spinner Loading with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, spinner

I wanted to make Spinner should appear when user clicks on Submit Button and Spinner should stop once the AJAX POST and GET request completed

Can you Please help me know How I make my below Angular Code to implement the feature.

Below is the Example I saw for Spinner in Angular

***[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/BGLUYcylbIVJRz6ztbhf?p=preview)***

Below is my AngularJS code .

```
  var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngTable"]);

    app.controller("Controller", ["$scope", "$http", "$window",
        function ($scope, $http, $window) {

            $scope.firstFunction = function () {
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'mainDeviceSite.php',
                    //headers : {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                    data: {
                        accountnumber: $scope.accountnumber
                    },
                }).then(function (response) {
                    var data = response.data;
                    $scope.post = response.data;
                    $scope.cellularIPAddressValue = response.data.devices;
                    console.log($scope.cellularIPAddressValue);

                    //$scope.secondFunction(data);
                }, function (error) {
                    var data = error.data;
                    console.log("Error" + data);
                })
            }

       $scope.secondFunction = function () {
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'BEPEvents.php',
                //headers : {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                data: {
                    accountnumber: $scope.accountnumber
                },
            }).then(function (response) {
                var data = response.data;
                $scope.post = response.data;

                var x2js = new X2JS();
                $scope.aftCnv = x2js.xml_str2json(response.data);
                $scope.bepValues = $scope.aftCnv.EEPEvents.BlobData;
                console.log($scope.bepValues);
            }, function (error) {
                var data = error.data;
                console.log("Error" + data);
            })
        }
    }
]);
```

**HTML Code**

```
 <div class="example">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-group form-search">
                        <input type="text" ng-model="accountnumber" name="accountnumber" class="form-control search-query" placeholder="Enter Account Number">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                     <button type="submit" ng-click="firstFunction();secondFunction()" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                     </span>
                        <span id="message">{{message}}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: use a variable and inside then function set it to true and then use $timeout to set it back to false and then within html probably use ng-if or ng-show based on number of calls made..not a good way of handling but will get the job done...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Following solution

This applicable for all http request that are use in angular controller. When you call http request then spinner and progress bar you shows

[Demo](http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar/)

Refer this [angular-loading-bar](https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-loading-bar).

include the loading bar as a dependency for your app. If you want animations, include ngAnimate as well. note: ngAnimate is optional

```
angular.module('myApp', ['angular-loading-bar', 'ngAnimate'])
```

include the supplied JS and CSS file (or create your own CSS to override defaults).

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='build/loading-bar.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='build/loading-bar.min.js'></script>
```

Hope this is help you

Comment: I tried the above Solution But I am getting error in the console
`angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'fn' is not a function, got string
`